How to Transfer Multiple NFTs in One Transaction to a Solana Program?
I am trying to transfer multiple NFTs to a Solana smart contract in a single transaction. Here's the core idea:
I use the remaining_accounts array to pass the metadata, user NFT accounts, and vault NFT accounts for each NFT.
The nft_stake function processes the list of NFT mint addresses and performs the required validation and transfer operations.
Each NFT is validated to belong to a specific collection using its metadata.
However, I encounter lifetime errors in the following parts of the code:
remaining_accounts.chunks_exact(3) when splitting accounts for processing.
&ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info() while passing accounts for the _transfer_tokens function.
   let remaining_accounts = ctx.remaining_accounts;

   pub fn nft_stake(ctx: Context<NFTStake>, nft_mints: Vec<Pubkey>) -> Result<()> {
        let metadata_account_info = &accounts_chunk[0];
        let user_nft_account_info = &accounts_chunk[1];
        let vault_nft_account_info = &accounts_chunk[2];
        ...
    
        for (nft_mint, accounts_chunk) in nft_mints.iter().zip(remaining_accounts.chunks_exact(3)) {
            ...

            require!(
                nft_belongs_to_collection(nft_mint, &vault.collection_mint, metadata_account_info)?,
                ErrorCode::InvalidCollection
            );        
            ...
            
            _transfer_tokens(
    
                user_nft_account_info,
                vault_nft_account_info,
                &ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
                &ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                &[],
                1,
            )?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }


What would be the best approach to handle these lifetime issues while ensuring multiple NFTs can be transferred in a single transaction? Is there any example or documentation that explains this?
